# Is it possible **to change an .sql file extension to like .myname** and still the software like wamp or sqlite can still read it?

Tags: mysql, sql, file-extension

Is it possible **to change an .sql file extension to like .myname** and still the software like wamp or sqlite can still read it??

-I was just thinking of the possibilities that changing the file extension to something custom could add to db security.

Answer (score 1):

Using sqlite3 in Python you can select any arbitrary file extension (as long as [a-zA-Z]{1,...}) without hindering the module in accessing the database-file.

Note, however, that changing a default file-extension to a different arbitrary one does **not** increase (or decrease for that matter) security of the data stored in the database **in any way**.

You'd have to test if other (SQLite-)implementations allow custom extensions as well, but either way, it would have not impact whatsoever on security.

Answer (score 1):

So long as the software in question does not limit itself to only recognizing files ending ".sql", it makes no difference whatsoever.

A file extension is *just a label* - they do not affect the actual physical contents of a file *in any way*, and an SQL file is *just a text file*. That `.sql` extension is really more of a user aid than a software aid - whilst software will use it as a filter (such as only showing `.doc` files by default on Word's Open dialog), if you tell a program to treat file X as a file of format Y then it will attempt to read it as a Y-formatted file, regardless of extension.

You could change it to `.txt` and (under Windows) it would open in Notepad instead when double-clicked, or `.doc` and it would open in Word (probably incorrectly, as Word would attempt to parse it as a Word-formatted file, not a plain text file). The actual contents of the file are *completely* unaffected.

You could change the `.sql` to `.txt` or `.doc` or `.bmp` or `.wahoo` or anything (or even remove the extension entirely), it will still be readable by WAMP etc.

It will have absolutely zero effect on security.